# running a batch script across different drives

Tags: batch-file, iis-7, fastcgi, application-pool

I need to run this bat script on an F:/ drive.

```
Cd "c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\"
appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:mywebsite.com
TIMEOUT /T 10
appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:mywebsite.com
```

Is there a way to make it work?

When I run this script ( from c: to c: ) , it works. 
But my watch dog php script is on an f:/ drive.

Both the c: and f: are on the same server.

Comment: check out `cmd /?`. Note the `/d` parameter.

Comment: you are absolutely right. that did it, but it introduced me the following problem. "message:Configuration error Filename: redirection.config Line Number: 0 Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions . " which is normal because IUSER do not have the ADMIN privileges. Any suggestions?

Comment: our IIS 7 server started to go down 3-4 times a day and we have to manually stop and start its app pool. I wrote a watch dog script to do this programmatically & automatically ( to minimize the down time ) but the buck has stopped with that permission deal. Cannot figure out from the EVENT VIEWER what it is that causes to go down.

Answer (score 0):

Stephan got that right. /D is the answer.